# MobileNet TF-Slim implementation graph freezing

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I retrained the in TF-Slim implemented MobileNet on a custom dataset. This worked fine, but now I want to freeze the graph, so that I can deploy the model to an app. The problem now is, that I really can't figure out which are the input and output node names. I already inspected the graph but I didn't find something. I already searched and tried multiple possibilities for the input and output node names, but no one worked.

MobileNet TF-Slim Version which I'm using: [Link to Model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.py)

I also tried all Tensorflow versions from 1.0.0 to 1.5.0 but no one worked for the possible input and output names.

Comment: I might running into the same problem, not solved yet. it seems that slim have own naming styles and unable to set names like tf.nn.conv2d(). if you save your graph with plane text, and open it you could find the nodes and names. it's quite different and I am checking out how to understand that.